# Finding the centroid of a polar curve

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The curve is $r = e^{-b\theta}$ where $b > 0$ and  $θ \in [0, \infty)$.

I got that the arc length is $\frac{\sqrt{b^2 + 1}}{b}$ (is this correct?), but computing the centroid $(x, y)$ looks awful.  I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Now, wouldn't x = (1/L) lim_T-->∞ ∫[0 to T] e^(-bθ) ds? But I don't know how to compute that integral!!

Comment: What is the centroid of a _curve_?  A region in the plane has a centroid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your curve has the parametric representation
$$\gamma:\quad \theta\mapsto(e^{-b\theta}\cos\theta, e^{-b\theta}\sin\theta)\qquad(0\leq\theta<\infty)\ .$$
It follows that
$$ds=\sqrt{(x'(\theta))^2+(y'(\theta))^2}\ d\theta=\sqrt{1+b^2}\ e^{-b\theta}\ d\theta\ .$$
The centroid $(\xi,\eta)$ of $\gamma$ is characterized by the so-called *moment equations*
$$\xi \ L(\gamma)=\int_\gamma x\ ds,\qquad \eta\ L(\gamma)=\int_\gamma y\ ds\ .$$
You already have computed $L(\gamma)={\sqrt{1+b^2}\over b}$. In addition we need
$$\int_\gamma x\ ds=\sqrt{1+b^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-2b\theta}\ \cos\theta\ d\theta=\ldots={2b\sqrt{1+b^2}\over 1+4b^2}$$
and
$$\int_\gamma y\ ds=\sqrt{1+b^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-2b\theta}\ \sin\theta\ d\theta=\ldots={\sqrt{1+b^2}\over 1+4b^2}\ .$$
It follows that
$$\xi={2b^2\over 1+4b^2},\qquad \eta={b\over1+4b^2}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I've never seen it asked that a student find the centroid of a polar curve, so I'm not sure of the context for your problem.  I would guess, since the curve is a one-dimensional object in a two-dimensional space (the plane), that you are being asked to find the point at which one-half of the total arclength (which is finite) is reached, passing inward from $\theta = 0$.  (And I'm leaving this as an answer, rather than a comment, since I don't have enough rep yet...)

EDIT: I concur with your arclength result, so you want to find the value of $\theta$ at which you reach an arclength of $\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2}}{2b}$, then evaluate the radius of the curve there.*  If you're asked to give the Cartesian coordinates, you can then also carry out the requisite transformation.

*Interestingly, this result is independent of  $b$.

Comment: I don't know how to do the centroid though! help!

Comment: You presumably calculated the arclength using

Comment: You presumably calculated the arclength using $\sqrt{1+b^2}\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-b\theta} d\theta $ to get the answer you quoted.  Now set the upper limit of the arclength integral to some unknown angle $\Theta$ ; you will get an arclength function which you set equal to  $\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2}}{2b}$.  You would then solve this for the angle $\Theta$; this is the angle at which the midpoint of the arclength occurs.  You can put this into the polar curve equation to get $r$.  With the polar coordinates in hand, you can convert these to rectangular coordinates.